# Dynamic Programming - Job Selection

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

I am attempting at solving a Job Selection problem using Dynamic Programming. The problem is as follows:
 - There is one job offering every day with varying payouts every day
 - You cannot work three days in a row (if you work on day 1 and 2, you must take a break on day 3)
 - Come up with a job schedule to work on to maximize the amount of money you make

I have formalized the input and output of the problem as follows:

Input: P[1...n] a list of n positive numbers
Output: m, a max possible payout and A, a set of indexes {1,... n} such that if i is in A, and i+1 is in A, then i+2 is not in A. m is equal to a summation of P[i] for all values i in set A.

I am stuck on the thought process of making a self-reduction, and subsequently a dynamic programming algorithm in order to calculate the maximum earnings.

Any assistance is highly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually dynamic programming is relatively straightforward once you decide how much state you need to take account of at each point, and your solution is efficient or not depending on whether your choice of state is good.

Here I would suggest that the state at each point is whether it is 0, 1, or 2 days since the last break. So for each day and 0,1,2 days since a break I calculate the max possible payout up to and including that day, given that it is 0,1,2 days since a break.

For 0 days since a break the max payout is the max possible payout for any state on the previous day. There is no contribution for that day, since you are taking a break.

For 1 days since a break the max payout is the payout for that day plus the max possible pay from all previous days for the state of 0 days since a break for that day.

For 2 days since a break the max payout is the payout for the current and previous days plus the max possible payout for two days ago and a state of 0 days since the last break on that day.

So you can calculate the max payouts from left to right, making use of previous calculations, and the overall max is the max payout associated with any state on the final day.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to formule the answer in this way:

### Solutions:

X=[x1, x2, ..., xn] in [0,1]^n |  xi + xj + zk <= 2 for each k=i+2=j+1, i>=1, k<=n.

### Maximize:

f(X)= Sum(xi*vi) for i in [1, N],  where vi is the payout of working day i.

Then recursive algorithm has to decide wether if it works a day or if not to maximize the function, taking into acount the restraints of Solution. That is a very simple basic schema for DP.

Answer (score 0):

Mcdowella explains the choice of states and transitions pretty well for this particular DP problem. The only thing left to add is a graph representation. Hope it helps.
[Job Selection DP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9GVp.png)